# Laptop fan always working in ac mode

Tags: battery, cpu, fan

I have a Dell Inspiron 3521 laptop and I face a problem with its fan. It keeps working even when the CPU usage is low, making a really annoying loud noise. However, that problem appears only in ac mode. When I switch to battery mode, the fan stops working.

The laptop has also a windows partition. The problem doesn't appear at all when running windows 10. Is there any solution to that problem?

Comment: Go into the BIOS and see if there's a setting that enables "full power" when on AC.

Comment: I checked. There is no such setting or anything concerning the power consumption, the battery or the fan.